# StackOverflowError with BigInteger for calculating C(n,r)

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I implemented the recursive algorithm to calculate N choose r.
C(n,r) = C(n-1,r-1) + C(n-1,r).
I wanted to calculate C(100000, 50000), which is throwing stackoverflow. Appreciate any help.

Error:

> java Solution 1
>           1
>           10000 5000
>           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
>       at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3210)
>       at java.lang.String.(String.java:215)
>       at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:430)
>       at Solution.findNcr(Solution.java:31)
>       at Solution.findNcr(Solution.java:35)

Code:

```
private static HashMap<String,BigInteger> hm =
    new HashMap<String,BigInteger>(10000000,0.9f); 
private static BigInteger findNcr(int n, int r) {
    BigInteger topLVal = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    BigInteger topRVal = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    int parentN = 0, parentR = 0;

    if( r >= n-r)  //ncr = nc(n-r)
       r = n-r;

    if (r == 0 || r == n)
        return BigInteger.valueOf(1L);
    else if (r == 1 || r == n-1)
        return BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    else if (hm.containsKey(""+n+""+r)) { //line 31
        return hm.get(""+n+""+r);
    } else{
        parentN = n-1; parentR = r-1;
        topLVal = findNcr(parentN, parentR);
        topRVal = findNcr(parentN, r);
        hm.put(""+parentN+""+parentR,topLVal);
        hm.put(""+parentN+""+r, topRVal);
        return topLVal.add(topRVal);      //line 35
    }
}
```

Comment: Every recursive algorithm can be converted to iterative form, and vice versa. So you just have to find out how to write it using for's and while's.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out a way but that would entail creating an two dimensional array of size N*R and for my requirement N <= 100000000, so i would be using up space of the order of 100000000*50000000 (worst case). So, i went ahead with using this top-down approach with a hash map for cache. I should try the iterative approach and see how it performs. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Well what you did is what you got. Every recursive call you make saves the caller state on the stack and since you are calculating C(100000, 50000) which will make multi million recursive calls will end up with all stack space getting exhausted. You may want to look into a better algorithm like i mentioned here [Write a faster combinatorics algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650327/write-a-faster-combinatorics-algorithm/8651998#8651998)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was reluctant to implement an algorithm that would do multiplications and divisions, as they are expensive. so, I went with this dynamic programming approach. I will try your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You could try increasing your stack size.

Use -Xss to your JVM.

I guess 1 GB should do the trick for you.
You can calculate it to get more accurate value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to figure out a solution that would use the least possible space and run faster.

Comment: Does it have to be recursive algorithm?

Comment: need not be a recursive algorithm!

Answer (score 1):

This simple implementation is running up to 10s for 100000 | 50000.

(for real use you should add some checks and different approach when r < n - r. (just for cycles would have different bounderies... not radical change)

```
private static BigInteger ncr(int n, int r) {
    BigInteger top = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger bot = BigInteger.ONE;

    for(int i = n; i > r; --i){
        top = top.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }

    for(int i = r; i > 1; --i){
        bot = bot.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }

    return top.divide(bot);
}
```

Comment: +1 I took the liberty of making your code a little more efficient by avoiding the need to create Strings.